# Sync multiple sliders of bxslider onTouchMove

Tags: jquery, slider, synchronization, bxslider, touchmove

I have 2 sliders on a page, I want to sync both of them. I found a solution to sync on click of external controls but how do I trigger on swipe left and right?

http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/1/

```
<!-- slider 1 -->
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
</ul>

<!-- slider 2 -->    
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>Slide 4</li>
    <li>Slide 5</li>
    <li>Slide 6</li>
</ul>

<!-- custom controls -->
<div class="bxslider-controls">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">PREV</a>
  <a class="pull-right" href="#">NEXT</a>
</div>
```

---

JS

```
var slider_array = new Array();

$(document).ready(function ($) {

// launch bxslider
$('.bxslider').each(function (i) {
    slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({
        controls: false
    });
});


// bind controls on custom controls, and run functions on every slider
$('.bxslider-controls a').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('pull-left')) {
        $.each(slider_array, function (i, elem) {
            elem.goToPrevSlide();
        });

    } else if ($(this).hasClass('pull-right')) {
        $.each(slider_array, function (i, elem) {
            elem.goToNextSlide();
        });
    }
});
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as much as I can do to get the 2 sliders (**with the same number of slides**) to be in sync.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMAtL/)

```
 var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   onSlideNext: doThis,
   onSlidePrev: doThis
 });
 var slider1 = $('.bxslider1').bxSlider({
   onSlideNext: doThis,
   onSlidePrev: doThis
 });

function doThis(ele, old, newi){
  slider.goToSlide(newi);
  slider1.goToSlide(newi);
}
```

What I did is assigned a function to its onSlideNext and onSlidePrev events and this function ensured both the sliders moved to the same index (this is why I emphasized on the same number slides).

Disclaimer: I do not endorse this kind of approach nor do I claim that this is a fully tested solution :) :) :)

Comment: The only issue with this is that it slides the wrong direction on the first or last slides.

Comment: Simple approach to address that, 5 just needs to be the index of your last slide:

    `function doThis(ele, old, newi){
        if(old == 0 && newi == 5) {
            slider.goToPrevSlide();
            slider1.goToPrevSlide();
        } else if(old == 5 && newi = 0) {
            slider.goToNextSlide();
            slider1.goToNextSlide();
        } else {
            slider.goToSlide(newi);
            slider1.goToSlide(newi);  
        }
    }`